# If String Value is empty, 0 , or Null MS Access, SQL, VBA

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I'm trying to get figure out a work around for this coding.

Essentially this code checks the values of fields in Table CFRRR if `program` and `language` match the values in table attendance `Programs` and `Language`.

This normal code works. However, if there is not a matching value for `language` then the code continues to just loop.

I want to adjust the code to go to the next `strSQL` if there is no matching `language`, but I can't get it to run through the next `strSQL`.

I think my error is that I am not writing the `IF/THEN` statement correctly. Here's the code:

```
a = Program
b = language

strSQL = "SELECT TOP 1 userID FROM attendance where attendance.Programs LIKE '*" & a & "*' AND attendance.Language LIKE '*" & b & "*' AND Status = 'Available' AND attendance.Tracking = 0"

Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)

If strSQL = Null Then
    strSQL = "SELECT TOP 1 userID FROM attendance where attendance.Programs LIKE '*" & a & "*' AND Status = 'Available' AND attendance.Tracking = 0"
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)
End IF
```

Thank you :)

Comment: @Bohemian this is my _problem statement_: **However, if there is not a matching value for language then the code continues to just loop.** and.. **but I can't get it to run through the next strSQL. I think my error is that I am not writing the IF/THEN statement correctly.**

Comment: Harsh judgement by Bohemian. Lilly, strSQL will never be _null_, since your setting it to the SQL string. Check the recordset instead (if it's empty or not).

Comment: Hi @Mackan I agree! I was kind of shocked to be honest, but it's all good. I understand what you're saying. Should I check the recordset after the initial strSQL?

Comment: `rs` either contains records or not. So you'll need to check if after `Set rs = ...`. But, and this is probably one of the reasons Bohemian put this on hold, I can't see any loop that you describe. I can't follow your logic, but I can say that the `if strSQL = null` is not correct.

Comment: @Mackan you're right, the loop is at the bottom of this full code. I try not to put full code just because it can be so large and people don't have the time to read the full code. I guess I'll add it for reference. So for the checking after the `set rs = ...` would something like this: `If rs!UserID = Null Then` work? Because if the UserID is not set to a value I know there wasn't a language that matched.

Comment: @lilly perhaps it was a little harsh, but most of code you posted is irrelevant to the problem. I'll reopen it, but I was hoping you could reduce it  to the *minimum* needed to demonstrate the problem (ie a couple of lines or just the SQL). See [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: @Bohemian I understand, I removed whatever I could, but the rest of the code I feel is necessary for the question. Thank you.

Comment: @lilly it's OK. Good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should change it to

```
   Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)

If rs.recordcount =0  Then

    strSQL = "SELECT TOP 1 userID FROM attendance where attendance.Programs LIKE '*" & a & "*' AND Status = 'Available' AND attendance.Tracking = 0"
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)
End IF
```